# /usr/bin/setleds not working

Tags: raspbian

When I run the following (as root) on RPi (Raspbian, Model 3), the USB keyboard <kbd>numlock</kbd> LED should light up, but doesn't.  Variants using +caps and +scroll don't have any effect on the USB keyboard LEDs either.

```
# /usr/bin/setleds -v -L +num < /dev/console
```

This command works fine on several x86 based computers running Debian.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

`setleds` works fine on my Pi3. (You don't need `sudo`) when run from the console.

I am not sure why you are using `< /dev/console` .

Are you trying to run this in a script?

`/dev/console` is obsolete, but should work, although the normal virtual console on the Pi is `console=tty1`

Comment: Thanks much for your fast, friendly response.  You are correct that my use of /dev/console should have been /dev/tty1 (also works with tty7).  Still, I find that "scroll lock" cannot be controlled.  Are you able to control the "scroll lock" LED?